# How to write Junit Mockito test for Okttp in java

Tags: java, junit, mockito, okhttp

I am trying to write junit mockito test for this method. I am trying to figure out how to wirte junit for the post call

```
public StatusResponse getstatusResponse(){
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, scope);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("url")
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("Authorization","4jjf")
                .addHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
}
```

Comment: You don't call `new OkHttpClient()` (in general, the guideline is not to call `new` on objects that _do_ things, only objects that have values), and you take that as a parameter to your class's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should use OkHttp MockWebServer or similar approach instead of mockito to test these calls.

See https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver

```
  // Create a MockWebServer. These are lean enough that you can create a new
  // instance for every unit test.
  MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();

  // Schedule some responses.
  server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("hello, world!"));
  server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("sup, bra?"));
  server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("yo dog"));

  // Start the server.
  server.start();

  // Ask the server for its URL. You'll need this to make HTTP requests.
  HttpUrl baseUrl = server.url("/v1/chat/");
```